# Use code without using window onload event

Tags: javascript

I want to use the below code to add an `onClick` event to a button.

```
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("click", changeHeight);

function changeHeight() {
    var panelH = document.getElementById('second');

    if (panelH.style.height == '') 
        panelH.style.height = '160px';
    else 
       panelH.style.height = '';
}
```

but just works when is wrapped inside this:

```
window.onload = function() {

}
```

What should I change in other to use that code without using `window.onload` event?

Comment: why don't you want to put it in `window.onload`? But anyway, it probably still works without, provided you put the JS code (or the `<script>` tag which loads the code) *below* the relevant element in the document. (This is one reason why it's recommended to put most JS at the bottom of the `<body>`.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I use window.onload other elements (buttons) stop working.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine - try running the code snippet below. I would guess that you have put your script tag in `head` rather than in the bottom of `body`. Thus the script is ran before there is an element with `id=first`. So if this is the case then just move your script tag to the bottom of body (it's where people tend to put their script tags).

```js
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("click", changeHeight);


function changeHeight() {
       var panelH = document.getElementById('second');

       if (panelH.style.height == '') 
           panelH.style.height = '160px'
       else 
           panelH.style.height = ''
}
```

```css
#second {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="first">Change height</button>
<div id="second">Test</div>
```